# Why does the line "d = u2.connect() "still not work after connecting the phone with USB?

Tags: python, android

In Pycharm IDE, code no error, after running an error :RuntimeError:Can't find any android device/emulator

**Code:**

```
import uiautomator2 as u2  # 引用ui自动化库

money = 0  # 本次抢红包抢到的数额
d = u2.connect()  # 连接好安卓设备
d.app_start("com.tencent.mm")  # 打开微信
```

**Expectation**:Fix the RuntimeError error,Let Pycharm identify the computer connected to the phone
**Actual result**:RuntimeError: Can't find any android device/emulator

**Tried:**
The phone has been successfully connected:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8DnNq.png)

**Description**:When I connect my phone to my computer via USB and click the "Transfer data/file" option, then I send a red envelope on wechat and then run the code, the error is:RuntimeError: Can't find any android device/emulator.Running first and then sending a red envelope also shows above error.

Comment: Your screenshot only shows that there is an MTP connection for transferring files. uiautomator requires adb access. So you have to enable developer options and adb and on PC side install the appropriate USB drivers for the adb device and potentially the USB compound device .

Comment: Thank you very much. According to your suggestions, I searched the knowledge points of uiautomator2 and found that it is related to app automation testing. I will try to understand it this holiday!